# How to implement the button click functionality in bots with respective cards

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, bots, adaptive-cards

Hi I am working on Bot in that I have a requirement like when an user click the button I want to display the related content in next card like this below.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to implement the above scenario in bots by using any cards like adaptive cards, rich cards or Thumbnail cards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Adaptive Cards, you can use `AdaptiveSubmitAction` for that:

```
new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
{
    Data = "show me the next card"
};
```

This produces a new incoming message with `message.Text` being the value of `Data` and you can process it the same way as a regular message from user.

You can achieve the same with other rich cards / Thumbnail cards, using `ImBack` and `PostBack` actions:

```
new CardAction()
{
    Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
    Value = "show me the next card"
}
```

The `AdaptiveSubmitAction` also has `DataJson` property that you can use instead of `Data` (the `DataJson` has no effect if you use both). You can put a json structure there, that will end up in `message.Value` of the incoming message, while `message.Text` will be null in that case.

This can be handy when you need to pass more details, e.g. `DataJson = "{ \"CardName\": \"City\", \"Name\": \"New York\" }"` could mean you want to open some City card for New York. Then you can retrieve the structure like this:

```
protected override async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
    {
        var message = await item;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Text))
        {
            dynamic value = message.Value;
            if (value == null)
            {
                // empty message - show help, error etc.
            }
            dynamic cardName = value.CardName;
            // check the name, respond with the wanted card ...
        }
        else
        {
            // process as usual
            await base.MessageReceived(context, item);
        }
    }
```

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-AdaptiveCards) is a sample project that uses the json approach.

Comment: I already did that but I can't under stand the how to pass the value to my message to bot.  In the above mentioned example scenario they all are providing the details and getting the values but in my scenario I want to click the button and press the value like as text for that is there any possibility and without passing the json data can I processed that... please let me inform if there any possibility..

Comment: Do you mean you want to use Adaptive cards and have the value in the `Text` property of the message? I use the json approach to pass more information, but I found out that you can just set your text to `Data` instead of `DataJson` and it does exactly that. I updated the answer, see if it helps.